# Can i import theme variables to custom less file?

Tags: magento2.3.1, less, variables

I want to add a variable that located in "`web/css/source/_theme.less`" to my custom less file, that I created specialy for home page. I added my less file in "`Magento_CMS/layout/cms_index_index.xml`"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/home.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

In this home file i wrote

```
@baseDir: '../';
@import 'source/_theme.less';
@import 'source/_home.less';
```

but it doesn't import variable from "`_theme.less`" to my "`_home.less`" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create _extend.less file in your source folder

After you import all files in _extend.less like below, Also create _variable.less and add variable in this file.

```
@import 'source/_theme.less';
@import 'source/_home.less';
@import 'source/_variable.less';
```

Hope this will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

did you try the full path of less file?

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply. In all files that i saw (and in lib folder) import path should be written like this. Furthermore, if i delete `@import 'source/_theme.less';` everything is imported in home.less